How can we store and re populate form values when a control is unregistered
I have a reactive form featuring a toggle that mounts and unmounts (unregisters) a substantial child form within the main form.
When the user checks the checkbox, we display a new form (which is substantial) that the user needs to fill out.
After filling out the child form, if the user unchecks the checkbox, we unregister the child form and remove it from the DOM. However, this results in losing all the information previously filled out by the user in the child form, necessitating the user to refill all the information again.
We tried using unregister('field', {keepValue: true}), which retains and repopulates the data, but we don't want the values to persist when the form is submitted after unregistering a control.
In the below sample, we want to populate back the userDetails even after unmounting the userDetails, But not want to see the userDetails when the form is submitted without accepting T&C.
Please advise if there is an alternative approach to achieve this. Thanks in advance.


You could keepValue = true and conditionally remove those values from the data object in onSubmit().
Alternatively, you could use state.
  const [updatedUserDetails, setUpdatedUserDetails] = useState({
    firstName: "",
  });

and
  {...register("userDetails.firstName", {
    onChange: (e) =>
      setUpdatedUserDetails({
        ...updatedUserDetails,
        firstName: e.target.value,
      }),
    value: updatedUserDetails.firstName,
  })}


Thank you, we did try similar solutions. The first option is not scalable as we have many controls which needs this logic and the second one will cause re-renders which we want to prevent. I think this can be a feature request for react-hook-forms.
